# Adding logging in Lotus Notes form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I want to add logging capabilities in my Lotus Notes application. Basically I want to be able to log who make the change, when the change is made, and what field(s) is/are changed in a document. What is the best way to do this? I am thinking to also add this at the end of each document so the user knows who make the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before using LotusScript.  It's a bit of a pain, but the basic idea is to:

- Create an array or new document object within the QueryOpen event, and store the values for all the items in the current document.
- In your QuerySave event, compare the values of the current document to the in-memory copy you made, and then log any differences.

You can create a field on the form to write these changes to, and just append to it each time.

Watch out for other event handlers that make changes everytime the document opens, though.  You may need to copy original values in the PostOpen event, for example, if you change some fields in the QueryOpen event each time the doc opens, otherwise you'd get false change logs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am having problem with this. Here is how I set it up:  
Global Declaration:
[code]
Dim originalValues(2) As Variant
Dim lastValues(2) As Variant
[/code]  
[code]
Sub Queryopen(Source As Notesuidocument, Mode As Integer, Isnewdoc As Variant, Continue As Variant)
' Current document
 Dim doc As NotesDocument
 Set doc = Source.Document
 
' Array containing original value
 originalValues(0) = doc.QCR_No
 originalValues(1) = doc.QCR_Mobile_Item_No
 originalValues(2) = doc.QCR_Qty
End Sub
[/code]

Comment: Sorry, I am still trying to figure out how to use the markup. Let's try again  
Global Declaration  
'Dim originalValues(2) As Variant
Dim lastValues(2) As Variant`

Comment: I am reading how to use the markup but it does not seem to work for me. I have been trying to use the linebreak and inline code. Can anyone points out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The markup is limited in comments, so I think that's why you're having trouble.  Your best bet is to add a new question rather than extend this one in the comments.  If there's an answer here that you think is correct, mark it as accepted, otherwise leave it open and perhaps more answers will come.  Your new question can use the full markup to show what's giving you trouble.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I am in the process of doing this and I do not understand one thing.  what happens after I compared all the fields from the the ones in QueryOpen and PostSave. What I have in mind is here:

Comment: 1. Get all the original values in the QueryOpen
2. Make changes to the doc, then save
3. When it hit the PostSave events, do all the comparison
4. Get all the difference, then assign the text to the field for logging
5. Save the doc again ==> This is where I am concerned, will there be an infinite loop since after I the logging I need to save the doc again but the Queryopen even will not be ran so it will still have the old value and it will keep doing it all over again. Is this true?

Comment: You're right, this should probably be in the QuerySave event, but after all your other code (which may potentially change field values) has run.

Answer (score 4):

OpenNTF has several tools for this purpose that you could use, including [Open Audit](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Open%20Audit) and [Audit Manager](http://auditmanager.openntf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A "brute force" approach can also work. Every time a document is saved, create a copy of that version to a (separate) database. This will build an audit trail of the documents. The documents can be compared to extract the changes.

There is quite some overhead in this approach, but in my experience it has been worth it. The implementation is simple and all changes are captured without affecting the actual document. All information that is needed is captured and available for (offline) processing.